# ScrapingHub and remote database

Tags: mysql, scrapy, scrapinghub

I'm creating a spider with scrapy, and I want to  use MySQL database to get start_urls in my spider. Now I would like to know if it's possible to connect scrapy-cloud to  a remote database?

Comment: Can I run a spider in scrapinghub with a remote database to get start_urls

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by overriding the `start_requests` spider method:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

You can basically do anything you want from there.

Mysql python is installed by default on the scrapy cloud. Docs: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you it was very helpfull

Comment: Now I override start_requests,  and give my IP address to host, exemple con = mdb.connect(host='192.168.1.2', user='root', passwd='admin', db='scrapinghub'). When I deploy the spider on ScrapingHub I get this error:  Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.26'

Comment: Hi, this isn't you public IP, this is you local network address. To find you public IP visit http://httpbin.org/ip from the machine that's hosting the mysql server.

Comment: With my public IP address provided by http://httpbin.org/ip. I get the same error

Comment: Are you sure the server is listening for connections from non-local machines?

Comment: You are having trouble with your network setup. In order to access the Internet on the server where you are hosting your database, you are using NAT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation probably using commodity firewall. You need to configure your firewall to allow this traffic, which is way way beyond the original scope of this question.